# yadcf autocomplete not working as in original examples

Tags: autocomplete, yadcf

In the older examples of the AutoComplete filter, as soon as you typed in a letter the filtering was applied reducing the numbers of rows shown. For example, if I typed the letter "x", only rows with that column containing the letter "x" would be displayed.

```
{ column_number : 1, filter_type: "auto_complete" },
```

In the newer examples, the AutoComplete filter does not do this. I want the original functionality for my web page - how do I achieve this? Is there an option I need to pass to the AutoComplete plugin via the filter_plugin_options parameter? Or is there a different filter I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't recall that `aytocomplete` ever worked this way, you need to use the `filter_type: 'text'` instead, see the f[ourth column in the following showcase page](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html)

IMO triggering the filter on each keyboard type fits better the `text` filter rather then `autocomplete`

Comment: Yes - this was the showcase I was originally looking at.  I was thrown off because usage example on the html page shows the autocomplete filter type being used for the fourth column - but then I looked at the source of the page and into the dom_source_chosen_example.js script - and it does show then text filter type being used.  Thanks - my filter is working as expected now.